# Importing Google Maps Data into Blender with Renderdoc isn't Working

Tags: modeling

I have made multiple attempts to generate 3D maps into Blender from Google Maps. I resorted to different tutorials to see what I could possibly be doing wrong. All attempts would end with the same result via an error message stating that I wasn't in Satellite Mode when I saved the capture, although I was. I would like to know what else could be wrong if I have followed directions for installing Blender, Renderdoc, and Maps Model Importer, have them all run correctly, seemingly, but still get nothing but the same error message on every attempt? Do I need to reset anything in Blender to enjoy the benefits of the Maps Model Importer and Renderdoc?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this problem by installing a former stable version of RenderDoc. I had been running 1.10, and now I'm on 1.9 with no issues. I thought the problem was with Blender or my capture technique (eg, not moving the screen enough) but it turned out to be the version of RenderDoc.

Answer (score 0):

**June 2022**
**Success import:** using blender 3.1 / Maps Models importer addon 0.5 / Renderdoc 1.20

**Debug tips:**

1. Don't shake/move the mouse while capture (unlike some youtube tuts says).
2. Maybe you need to refresh G-Earth, reloading g-earth (reinjecting with renderdoc).

**Mesh detail tip**

1. Scale down the navigators googleEarth UI for better resolution/higher details at higher view/capture points. (Ctrl+MouseWheel pointing somewhere on the UI)